# How to evaluate the performance of the variational autoencoder

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, autoencoder, data-generation

I have a project which is about binary classification. The first class (class 0) contains 40,000 samples and the second one (class 1) contains 1200 samples. In order to handle this imbalance between the two classes, I used the [variational autoencoder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variational_autoencoder) (VAE) to generate new samples for the minority class.

I have split the dataset into training and test sets, The VAE is trained with all the data of the minority class in training set, and after generating new samples, I created a new dataset that contains the real data (training set) + generated data.

How can I evaluate the performance of my the VAE?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "performance" here? What do you want to measure?

Comment: I want to know if the generated data is similar to the real one (minority class),